# Joomla directory folder for email template and frontend image and links

Tags: php, css, joomla, content-management-system

I have two php files that I can't find.

1. Where can I find the email template for joomla? I would like to have a custom email template.
2. Where can I find the php file for the create/edit article in frontend image and links tabs? I have to fix the css because the user can't upload image on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of joomla templates, Please take a look on the below some of them are: link1[Link1](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/), [jNews](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/newsletter/jnews/), [emailtemp](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=860712)

Answer (score 0):

Please you can also this this below link, might be it will helpful to you

[Email Beautifier](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/email-beautifier)

Comment: Apart from the email beautifier, we have so many components, module and plugin, You can search in [http://extensions.joomla.org/](http://extensions.joomla.org/)